# $\iint f(x)g(y)dxdy =\int f(x)dx \int g(y)dy $ Why?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

$\iint f(x)g(y)dxdy =\int f(x)dx \int g(y)dy $ . How could this be proven I tried this with Fubini, so on the LHS we can think of $g(y)$ as constant and take it out of the integral and in the following step we can think ok $f(x)$ as a constant such. In other word $\int g(y) \big[\int f(x)dx\big]dy=\big[\int f(x)dx\big]\int g(y)dy$.

But I do not know how to come from $\int f(x)dx \int g(y)dy \Rightarrow\iint f(x)g(y)dxdy $ pls help

Comment: I really do not understand why i do get a downvote, if it is so trivial why does the person not answer ??

Comment: I downvoted because I found the question confusing. The question itself, trivial or not, is interesting.

Comment: If the question is interesting so why a downvote ?

Comment: As I said, I found it confusing. Maybe it's because I'm in mobile, but the equations seemed "strange". It's better now after Masacroso's edit, so I will remove the downvote.

Comment: ah ok could be the case sometimes mobile sucks on desktop everything seems legite

Answer (score 3):

Both expressions are the same. Note that

$$\iint f(x) g(y)\, dx\, dy=\int g(y)\left(\int f(x)\, dx\right)\, dy$$

because $g(y)$ is a constant for each $y$ in the inner integral. Now call $A:=\int f(x)\, dx$, then $A$ is a constant, assuming that the integral converges, and from above we knows that

$$\int g(y)A\, dy=A\int g(y)\, dy=\left(\int f(x)\, dx\right)\left(\int g(y)\, dy\right)$$

Revert the steps for the other direction of the proof (start by naming $A:=\int f(x)\, dx$ and put it inside of the other integral).

Comment: so my explanation was correct ? But would you agree that showing RHS is equal to LHS is more difficult then showing LHS is equal to RHS meaning that $\left(\int g(y)\, dy\right)\left(\int f(x)\, dx\right)=...=\int\int f(x) g(y)\, dy\, dx$

Comment: meaing that $\int g(y)\left(\int f(x)\, dx\right)\, dy = \int (g(y)\left(\int f(x)\, dx\right)\,) dy=\int \left(\int f(x) g(y) dx\right)\, dy$

Comment: But how are the breakets rules within an integral ? is $\int c(f(x))dx=\int cf(x)dx==\int (cf(x))dx$

Comment: ok, I think that what confuse you is the notation $\iint f(x) g(y) dx dy$. The notation is **defined** as $$\iint f(x)g(y)\,dx\, dy:=\int\left(\int f(x)g(y)\, dx\right)\, dy$$ Then, because $g$ is constant in the inner integral, then you can move out of the integral and also out of the bracket

Comment: yes, it holds that $$\int c(f(x))dx=\int cf(x)dx=\int (cf(x))dx$$ Here brackets (parenthesis) doesn't do something. If you are asking this kind of thing you really need a course in analysis, start by the integral of Riemann, and after take a look at the definition of the integral of Lebesgue as a limit of simple functions

Comment: yeah i know i was just asking for wheather it is ok genereally to put breackets such that $\int c(f(x))dx=\int (cf(x))dx$ do have the same meaning otherwise im ok with all the stuff. At first glance this did not seem trivial to me but after checking it was ok. But I think in general you have to be care full as $\int f(x)+g(x)dx $ is linear but same does not work for $\iint f(x)+g(y)dxdy \ne \int f(x)dx+\int g(y)dy$